# $(window) equivalent and other Jquery to Vannilla JS is not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of code;

```
class toTop {
  constructor(topButton) {
    this.topButton = topButton;
    this.topButton = $('#to_top');

    if (this.topButton.length > 0) {
      $(window).on('scroll', () => {
        return this.toggle($(window));
      });

      this.topButton.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      });
    }
  }

  toggle(trgt) {
    if (trgt.scrollTop() > 250) {
      return this.topButton.fadeIn();
    }
    return this.topButton.fadeOut();
  }

  render(trgt) {
    return trgt.append(this.topButton);
  }
}
```

I wanted to know the following things;

1. What is Pure Javascript only for `return this.toggle($(window))`. I tried using this;

   `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {`
      `return this.toggle($(window));`
   `});`

but not working.

Also, this part;

```
toggle(trgt) {
    if (trgt.scrollTop() > 200) {
      return this.topButton.fadeIn();
    }
    return this.topButton.fadeOut();
  }

  render(trgt) {
    return trgt.append(this.topButton);
  }
```

I tried converting to ES6 but no success. If any one can help would be great.

Comment: Why would you pass `window` to another function? It's a global variable, it's accessible anywhere, you don't need to pass it. Also, ["it's not working" is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 3):

The issue with this line of code you tried:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { return this.toggle($(window)); });
```

is that you forget that the scope of `this` changes. If you were to use an arrow function like you did with the jQuery example you'd have already solved the issue.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { return this.toggle($(window)); });
```

This can also be shortened a little more by removing the braces and `return`

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.toggle($(window)));
```

But then you still have the issue that `$(window)` and `$('#to_top')` isn't native to JavaScript, but is jQuery instead.

The closest native to `$(window)` would be `document.body` and the closest to `$('#to_top')` would be `document.getElementById('to_top')`, but that would break `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` because those aren't native JavaScript and are part of jQuery.

Comment: `$('#to_top')` => `document.getElementById('to_top') ` is not working.

Comment: what is the difference in `$('#to_top')` and `document.getElementById('to_top')` bcoz   when I use  `$('#to_top')` the scroll is working fine but when I use `document.getElementById('to_top')` nothing happens, it does not gives error as well. Does it have something to take with this condition `if (trgt.scrollTop() > 200)`.

Comment: @Sam scrollTop() is a jQuery function that gets the scrollTop property from a HTML element. Try removing the braces `()` and access it like a property. I highly recommend you learn the difference between jQuery, JavaScript and HTML.